# how to use turnery operator for display button

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i want to visible true and false a button according to below condition .
if Posted = true button will display and when Posted = false then button will not display 
so i want to use the turnery operator for this.

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
      CommandName="Update" Visible='<%# Bind("Posted") 
      ImageUrl="~/images/save.gif"  ValidationGroup="edit" />
```

please guide me .

Thanks 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use like below

```
  Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Bind("Posted"))%>'
```

If your have Boolean value in you `Posted`

Comment: @shekhar thanks but is this possible that when Posted is False than button will display . Thanks again